# access value in array from Json response typesciprt

Tags: json, angular, typescript

How can i access subjects in Json response and take the value which in types using typescript ?

Json Response :

```
{
"$id": "1",
"Council_ID": 102,
"place": "bla bla bla",
"number": "4644",
"type": 2,
"user_Id": 15,
"subjects": [
    {
        "$id": "2",
        "subjectCode": "464",
        "type": 1,
        "branch": "cairo",
        "gender": true
    },
    {
        "$id": "3",
        "subjectCode": "466",
        "type": 5,
        "branch": "alex",
        "gender": true
    }
],
"absence": []
}
```

meeting.component.ts :

```
this.dataStorageService.getCouncilId(this.meetingID).subscribe(response => {
                this.subjectsWithID = response.json();
                console.log(this.subjectsWithID, 'All Response')
                this.typee = this.subjectsWithID.subjects.type;
                console.log(this.typee, 'bla bla');
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to access the values

```
this.subjectsWithID.Council_ID; // 102
this.subjectsWithID.type; // 2
this.subjectsWithID.$id; // '1'
this.subjectsWithID.subjects[0].$id; // '2'
this.subjectsWithID.subjects[0].type; // 1
this.subjectsWithID.subjects[1].$id; // '3'
this.subjectsWithID.subjects[1].type; // 5
```

Comment: i got it ,Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your question. If so please provide some example of the desired output.

```
this.dataStorageService
    .getCouncilId(this.meetingID)
    .map(json)
    .map(response => response.subjects.map(subject => subject.type))
    .subscribe(response => { ... });
```

Comment: i wanna have the value of types to use it in another function .. i want to make this.typee = 1 the value of first element in subjects